# Different ways of object instantiation and their differences

Tags: java, c#

What is the difference between:

`Student s = new Student(); //instantiating in the same line as declaration`

```
Student s; 
s = new Student(); // instantiation and declaration in different lines
```

What is the advantage of using the second approach over the first? On what circumstances do we use these two approaches?

(The second approach is very evident in Collections)

Comment: Which is it?  Java or c#?

Comment: Nothing change, both are same, except readability counts

Comment: The only difference is you can have code in between if they are not on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

For Java, this really doesn't matter. Assuming that those two lines follow directly after each other. The only subtle difference:

```
1: Student s1, s2 = new Student();
2: s1 = new Student();
```

After line 1, s1 is **null**; but then the compiler will give you an error message if you would try to actually use the un-initialized s1.

I think the "best practice" is to "do things in one place". Meaning: you initialize variables right at their [declaration](http://java.about.com/od/d/g/declarationstatement.htm); and you only deviate from that rule when you have good reasons to do so. But please note that this is more of a *style* question.

Finally: the more important aspect in my eyes - at least when talking about **fields** of a class (and not local variables in methods); using the **final** keyword is the thing that you should prefer to do. Because then the compiler will force you to define your variable exactly once.

Comment: Schweet, all's good. :)

Comment: No one doubts the NullPointerException? I think it should be a compile error, in both C# and Java.

Comment: @DannyChen Good catch. You are fully correct, and nobody noticed yet. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In both C# and Java, `Student s;` declares a variable named `s` which is unassigned(uninitialized). You can't access it before its initialization.

```
Student s;
Student ss = s;  //compile error because s is not assigned
```

An uninitialized variable is different with `null`:

```
Student s = null;
Student ss = s;  //compiles fine
```

The two implementations in your question are both fine, but I'd prefer the first one-line code, because it's simpler. The second is useful when you want to initialize the variable with different types.

```
Fruit f;

if (wantApple)
{
    f = new Apple();
}
else
{
    f = new Orange();
}
```

Comment: `Fruit f = wantApple ? new Apple() : new Orange();`

Comment: @DavidArno First, this is not only Java because OP's question is tagged both Java and C#. Second, sometimes we have more than one `new` expression in the `if` block.

Comment: The ternary operator exists in C#, too. And if you have more than the one statement in the `if`, then refactor them out to separate methods and the ternary operator can still be used.

Comment: The ternary expression above won't compile in C# because C# doesn't infer the type of the expression from its assignment.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I always forget that annoying feature of C#.

Answer (score 1):

For C#, there is one significant difference between the two approaches. By declaring and assigning the variable in one statement, `var` can be used:

```
var s = new Student(); //compiler can infer that s is of type Student

Student s; // Type must be specified as it cannot be inferred.
s = new Student();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using construct function is always better. You also can use code like :

```
Student s = new Student(){
Name='abc',
Age=15
}
```

You can do some additional processing using the parameters passed to the constructor during initialization or if you want to ensure a coherent state just after calling the constructor. I prefer the first one.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public Student(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

But for readability/maintainability reasons, avoid creating constructors with too many parameters.

Answer (score -1):

This is what we call initialization:

```
Student s = new Student();
```

whereas this is just assignment:

```
s = new Student();
```

There is no important difference between that. In some cases we should use the second way, e.g while we are instanting the streams:

```
InputStream inputStream;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```